# Sort week day texts

Tags: python, sorting, datetime, python-2.7

I have list `["Tue", "Wed", "Mon", "Thu", "Fri"]` as list, I want to make it as
`["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"]`.

How to sort this?

Comment: You need an ordinal attached to each value (i.e. [1,2,3,4,5]), since an alphabetic sort won't work.  I assume this is a contrived example since, in practical terms, you can just create a list that has the expected order.

Comment: @skp: Mine is just a contrived example as well.  The point being, you have to add additional information for the ordering.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not very efficient, but if you have a list of the order they're supposed to be in...

```
>>> m = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"]
>>> n = ["Tue", "Wed", "Mon", "Thu", "Fri", "Tue", "Mon", "Fri"]
>>> sorted(n, key=m.index)
['Mon', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Fri']
```

Note, this will throw an exception if a certain value is present in `n` that isn't in `m`.

Or put them into a dict with name as key and order as value, then use `key=your_dict.get` as a key... something like:

```
>>> d = {name:val for val, name in enumerate(m)}
>>> d
{'Fri': 4, 'Thu': 3, 'Wed': 2, 'Mon': 0, 'Tue': 1}
>>> sorted(n, key=d.get)
['Mon', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Fri']
```

This won't throw an exception (except on Py3.x where you'll get an error on trying to sort `None`), but you could use a partial to sensible, sort before or after default, or to get equivalent behaviour of `list.index`, use `key=d.__getitem__` or similar

Answer (score 2):

Find and replace all instances of monday with 1, tuesday with 2, etc sort, reassign.

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

You are looking for a lexical sort. It’s also interesting to write your own function, as a learn matter ;)

EDIT: ok you just need a function that, for a day, returns its day week number. You can simply use an array of day string in the function, and then use the day week number to sort elements like a boss.

Comment: I don't see Lexical Sorting in your link.  Are you perhaps referring to Decorate-Sort-Undecorate?

Comment: Lexical sort won't work in your case. Based on your example you'll get ["Mon", "Fri", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed"] if you lexical sort this