# Sum values inside a list of tuples and order by weekday

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum, tuples

I have a list of tuples holding `('Day of Week', n)` as follows:

```
[('Wed', 1), ('Wed', 1), ('Thu', 1), ('Thu', 0), ('Tue', 0), ('Mon', 0), ('Sun', 0), ('Sat', 0), 
 ('Fri', 0)]
```

I want to produce the following output, a list of tuples holding `('Day of Week', sum_n)`, where `sum_n` is the sum of all the corresponding `n` values in my initial list. Note that the elements should be in order of weekday.

```
 [('Wed', 2), ('Thu', 1), ('Tue', 0), ('Mon', 0), ('Sun', 0), ('Sat', 0), ('Fri', 0)]
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Tuples are immutable. You just have to iterate, count and make new tuples and append them to a new list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a list comprehension:

```
>>> l = [('Wed', 1), ('Wed', 1), ('Thu', 1), ('Thu', 0), ('Tue', 0), ('Mon', 0), ('Sun', 0), ('Sat', 0), ('Fri', 0)]
>>> [(x, sum(y[1] for y in l if y[0] == x)) for x in set(z[0] for z in l)]
[('Sun', 0),
 ('Tue', 0),
 ('Mon', 0),
 ('Wed', 2),
 ('Sat', 0),
 ('Thu', 1),
 ('Fri', 0)]
```

To sort with second element descending:

```
>>> res = [(x, sum(y[1] for y in l if y[0] == x)) for x in set(z[0] for z in l)]
>>> sorted(res, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
[('Wed', 2),
 ('Thu', 1),
 ('Sun', 0),
 ('Tue', 0),
 ('Mon', 0),
 ('Sat', 0),
 ('Fri', 0)]
```

To sort by day of week ([more answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844158/sort-week-day-texts)):

```
>>> sorted_days = ["Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu"]
>>> sorted(res, key=lambda x: sorted_days.index(x[0]))
[('Fri', 0),
 ('Sat', 0),
 ('Sun', 0),
 ('Mon', 0),
 ('Tue', 0),
 ('Wed', 2),
 ('Thu', 1)]
```